# Remove ^@ characters from linux file

Tags: linux, unix, unicode, sed, utf-16

I have a file which has visible `^@` characters (blue) after each character. I can see these characters only in `vi file.txt`. I am unable to view these characters using `cat`. How can I remove them?

I tried using the following command:

```
sed "s/[^@]//g" a.txt > b.txt
```

However this didn't seem to alter the file.

Comment: You may use `dos2unix` to convert from DOS (windows stuff) to unix.

Comment: Likely you have a file in UTF16 encoding. In Linux you see it in your current locale which is byte oriented in most cases (even UTF-8). What you see as ^@ is ASCII code 0, the higher part of 16-bit symbol it's 0 for most Latin letters.

Comment: These are null bytes (0x00), likely due to your file being encoded as UTF-16 which uses two bytes for each character and thus for normal ASCII text has null bytes interlaced with the ASCII bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 <your-file> > <new-file>`

Comment: @user1882633 I get the following error:  iconv: incomplete character or shift sequence at end of buffer  Is there anyway you could help me as well? :D

Comment: Are you sure that your source file is a valid UTF16?

Answer (score 1):

`dos2unix file.txt file.txt`. This will do..

Comment: You need dos2unix >= 6.0 to be able to convert UTF-16 files to UTF-8 with it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
sed "s/[\^@]//g" a.txt > b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove all files in dir with inappropriate symbols in a such way:

```
for i in *.*;do 
  
  case "$i" in 
   
  *[\(\)\!\*\%\^\ ]*) 
    mv "$i" ${i//[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/_}
  ;;
  esac
   
done
```

*[()!*%^\ ]* -- stands for eliminate any symbol from the set of: ()!*%^ and space
[^a-zA-Z0-9.] -- stands for not English low and upper cases charecters, numbers and dots

What is important it only renames files containing 'bad' characters.